# Metabox save function looks like that it doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm currently working on creating meta boxes. I used the following tutorial and some self-adapted. Link of tutorial: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields/

Now I get the following error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: dsmeta_image in
>   /customers/0/d/a/xxx/httpd.www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ds-flexslider/includes/cpt-manager.php
>   on line 181 Notice: Undefined index: dsmeta_image_caption in
>   /customers/0/d/a/xxx/httpd.www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ds-flexslider/includes/cpt-manager.php
>   on line 181

It seems that the variable does not exist, I'm using an array fields for Metabox and created a foreach loop walk you through it if I understand correctly.

How is this problem.
It is in any event error when saving the meta boxes ...

The part of setting up the fields array:

```
// Create the fields array
$prefix = 'dsmeta_';
$custom_meta_fields = array(
    array(
        'label' => 'Image',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'image',
        'type' => 'image'
    ),
    array(
        'label' => 'Image caption',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'image_caption',
        'type' => 'text'
    )
);
```

Part of the saving function:

```
add_action('save_post', 'dsslider_manager_save_extras');
function dsslider_manager_save_extras($post_id) {
    global $custom_meta_fields;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // loop through fields and save the data
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    } // end foreach
}
```

### Update after request

Here I add the meta box for the fields :

```
    // Add meta box support
// This registers a function to be called when the WordPress admin interface is visited
add_action("admin_init", "dsslider_manager_add_meta");
function dsslider_manager_add_meta(){

    // Create this cool new meta box for Portfolio Options
    add_meta_box("dsslider-meta", "Brandbox Options", "dsslider_manager_meta_options", "brandbox-slider", "normal", "high");
}
```

And here is the function for building the meta fields :

```
function dsslider_manager_meta_options(){

    global $custom_meta_fields, $post;
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        // (integer) (optional) The post ID whose custom fields will be retrieved. 
        // Default: Current post
        return $post_id;
?>

<div class="dsslider_manager_extras">

    <div class="ds-metabox" data-max_rows="5" data-min_rows="0">

        <table class="meta ds-input-table">

<?php


        foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
            $custom = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true); // Returns a multidimensional array with all custom fields of a particular post or page. 

            // Past HTML markup
?>          

            <tbody class="ui-sortable">
            <?php 

                echo '<tr class="row">';
                echo '<td class="order"></td>';
                echo '<td>';

                switch($field['type']) {
                    // case items will go here

                    // image
                    case 'image':
                        $image = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/image.png';
                        echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';

                        if($custom) { 
                            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom, 'thumbnail'); 
                            $image = $image[0]; 

                        } // end if statement

                        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" class="custom_preview_image" alt="" />

                        <input type="button" class="button add-image" name="' . $field['id'] . '" value="' . $custom . '"><a href="#" class="remove-image">Remove Image</a>';
                    break;

                    // text
                    case 'text':

                        echo '<input type="text" class="text" name="' . $field['id'] . '" value="' . $custom . '">';

                    break;

                } //end switch

                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';

        } // End foreach loop
             ?>
            </tbody>
        </table><!-- End .meta ds-input-table -->

        <ul class="ds-repeater-footer hl clearfix">
            <li class="right">
                <a href="#" class="repeatable-add ds-button">Add New Slide</a>
            </li>
        </ul><!-- End ul.hl clearfix repeater-footer -->

    </div><!-- End .ds-metabox -->

</div><!-- End .dsslider_manager_extras -->

<?php           
}
```

Comment: I also have tried to replace de variable $new with:
`$new = $_POST[$field]['id'];` Error then is:

Warning: illegal offset type in ... on line 180

And i have give it a try with this snippet:
`$new = $_POST['field']['id'];` Eror for this was: Undefined index: field in ... on line 180.

Comment: The problem is exactly what it looks like: `$_POST[$field['id']]` - or rather `$_POST['dsmeta_image']` and `$_POST['dsmeta_image_caption']` are not defined indexes in your $_POST array. Can you show us what your custom form inputs look like?

Comment: Hi @maiorano84 thank you for your answer and help. Of course , I can also post some parts of it!

Comment: @maiorano84 I updated the question with the code. For research I have used the tutorial of WP tuts: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields/

Hope you can help me out. I have tried a lot today, but I haven't get the solution yet..

Comment: The code looks sound. When you inspect the input text elements in your custom meta box, what does the name attribute say?

Comment: Hmm.. Good question. I thought this was important. I followed the WP tuts tutorial as I say.. There snippet was:

`// textarea
case 'textarea':
 echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea>
  <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;`

Comment: No, I mean when you right-click the input field in your browser and select "Inspect Element", what do you see?

Comment: @maiorano84 Oh Sorry for not understanding it. When I check the input field with firebug, it will output the following:
`<input class="text" type="text" value="" name="dsmeta_image_caption">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the $custom_meta_fields array to both generate your input fields and grab information from the $_POST array using complimentary key names.

This wouldn't ordinarily be a problem, but the fact is that some of the fields that you're using aren't actually passing information to the $_POST array. An example:

```
case 'image':
    $image = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/image.png';
    echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';

    if($custom) { 
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom, 'thumbnail'); 
        $image = $image[0]; 

    } // end if statement

    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" class="custom_preview_image" alt="" />

    <input type="button" class="button add-image" name="' . $field['id'] . '" value="' . $custom . '"><a href="#" class="remove-image">Remove Image</a>';
break;

//Later on....
foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
    $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
    $new = $_POST[$field['id']]; //<-- BOOM
    if ($new && $new != $old) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
    } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
    }
} // end foreach
```

In that foreach loop, you're attempting to grab a variable $_POST['dsmeta_image'] which doesn't exist, as your form never passes that particular key. A simple fix would be something like this:

```
foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
    if(isset($_POST[$field['id'])){
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    }
    else
        continue;
} // end foreach
```

You also need to bear in mind that input fields of type Button DO NOT send information to the $_POST array. If this was your intention, you need to send the information you want via Hidden Field, or something else.

Hope this helps.